# ElasticSearch freezes upon startup after “[node] initializing …” state

Tags: elasticsearch

We have a production environment on ElasticSearch 1.6.0.

When we start elasticsearch service, although service status is "started", it does not bind to ports 9200/9300 and join the cluster.

When I check the log, I see that the node initialization process is stuck at `[node] initializing ...` state. **It does not proceed to [node] "initialized", "starting..." etc. states**. I pasted the log at the very below.

Thinking indices are corrupt, I stopped the service, renamed the folder where indices are stored and restarted the service. A new folder was created, but it was blank and the same problem continued.

One thing I noticed is that, the java process keeps running at 100% on one of the CPU cores, without any changes for hours, even days.

I am absolutely stuck as the service is not even bound to 9200 port to check its health via curl, and there are no error messages in log. There was not a single configuration change, no network connectivity issues, it has been running stable for several years, only the VM it was hosted was restarted (deallocated & reallocated).

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Note: A fresh installation or upgrade if not possible as the rest of the cluster is up and running.

```
[2020-01-25 16:31:27,064][INFO ][node] [sk-node-3] version[1.6.0], pid[1253], build[cdd3ac4/2015-06-09T13:36:34Z]
[2020-01-25 16:31:27,120][INFO ][node] [sk-node-3] initializing ...
[2020-01-25 16:31:27,210][INFO ][plugins] [sk-node-3] loaded , sites [head, bigdesk]
[2020-01-25 16:31:27,576][INFO ][env] [sk-node-3] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/datadrive2 (/dev/sdc1)]], net usable_space [26.9gb], net total_space [29.4gb], types [ext4]
[2020-01-25 16:31:31,786][INFO ][script] [sk-node-3] compiling script file [/etc/elasticsearch/scripts/calculate-score.groovy]
[2020-01-25 16:31:32,473][INFO ][script] [sk-node-3] compiling script file [/etc/elasticsearch/scripts/predict-item-score-5-latent.groovy]
[2020-01-25 16:31:32,539][INFO ][script] [sk-node-3] compiling script file [/etc/elasticsearch/scripts/predict-item-score-6-latent.groovy]
[2020-01-25 16:31:32,649][INFO ][script] [sk-node-3] compiling script file [/etc/elasticsearch/scripts/predict-item-score.groovy]
[2020-01-25 16:31:32,670][INFO ][script] [sk-node-3] compiling script file [/etc/elasticsearch/scripts/predict-item-score2.groovy]
[2020-01-25 16:31:32,697][INFO ][script] [sk-node-3] compiling script file [/etc/elasticsearch/scripts/predict-item-score3.groovy]
[2020-01-25 16:31:32,723][INFO ][script] [sk-node-3] compiling script file [/etc/elasticsearch/scripts/predict-item-score4.groovy]
[2020-01-25 16:31:32,767][INFO ][script] [sk-node-3] compiling script file [/etc/elasticsearch/scripts/user-similarity.groovy]
```

Comment: Can you read the hot_threads for the blocking node? See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/cluster-nodes-hot-threads.html

BTW: is the blank in the script's path correct (the blank after /etc/)? Maybe one of the scripts causes the pain. Remove all scripts, check if the node comes up. If so, add one script, gently, and make the node restart. If the node comes up, try the next script.

Comment: Blanks were typos, just fixed them thanks. The problem is, service is stuck too early to bind to 9200, so no curl requests can be made. Plugins/scripts are fine as  they work on other nodes without any problems. The only change is that virtual machines were deallocated and reallocated on Azure cloud. Could a minor config change (processor type etc.) after this reallocation have caused JVM to crash?

Comment: as a workaround: can you join a complete fresh node to the cluster and let the replication do the work?

Comment: Any help will be appreciated. This issue is still unresolved.